# tomcat path when saving file in spring mvc

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I want to save uploaded files in tomcat directory, and after it i want to get some users access to download that files.
Now files are saving in eclipse directory, or on disc where eclipse is saved, but never in tomcat directory. I don't know how to get access to path of tomcat, i don't want to give:
C:\tomcat7\webapps\blabla\, i want to get path where ever tomcat is.

Upload Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload")
public class UploadController
{
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getUploadForm(Model model)
  {
    model.addAttribute(new UploadItem());
    return "upload/uploadForm";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String create(UploadItem uploadItem, BindingResult result)
  {
    if (result.hasErrors())
    {
      for(ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors())
      {
        System.err.println("Error: " + error.getCode() +  " - " + error.getDefaultMessage());
      }
      return "upload/uploadForm";
    }

    // Some type of file processing...

    String fileNameToCreate = "/"+uploadItem.getFileData().getOriginalFilename();
    File file;
    try {
    file = new File(fileNameToCreate);
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, uploadItem.getFileData().getBytes());

    } catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");
    System.err.println("Test upload: " + uploadItem.getName());
    System.err.println("Test upload: " + uploadItem.getFileData().getOriginalFilename());
    System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");

    return "redirect:/app/";
  }
}
```

I wish someone have some ideas to get path from this controller to tomcat, or how i can fixed it

Comment: You would never normally store files in the Tomcat directory.  Generally speaking you'd have some sort of file store like Amazon S3.  I think any approach that stores files uploaded by the user into Tomcat just sounds like a bit of a bad idea.

Comment: What @david99world said. :)

Comment: I double @david99world. Your application will not be portable. Imagine it is deployed to the tomcat on system where tomcat folder is read-only for security purposes. You need a way to configure place to store files. This parameter (path to folder) is a typical deployment parameter, you may pass it as a environment variable or as a system property for example.

Comment: than what you suggest, save files in database? or what if not database will be best to save files, and than give users with some rights possibilty to download this files

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following to get your tomcat folder:

```
System.getProperty("catalina.base");
```